# layer-list item height/width not working on pre-lollipop Android versions

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-drawable, xml-drawable

Why layer-list item height/width not working on pre-lollipop Android versions? I don't get any warnings like "Attribute height is only used in API level 21 and higher (current min is 16)", so that means that item height/width is included in some android support libraries I included to my project. But why it is not working? Maybe I need to include some more libraries or dance a cha cha cha? Here are my dependecies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.8.0'
```

Also switched this in my defaultConfig:

```
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    renderscriptTargetApi 25
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
```

Without height/width I can't create the drawable I need.

Comment: see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html#setLayerWidth(int,%20int) and https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html#setLayerHeight(int,%20int)

Comment: is there any way to set height/width to pre-lollipop layers?

Comment: no,  min sdk level is 23